# Selection Sort wrong output

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection-sort

I am trying to understand the SelectionSort for arrays.

If I understand it correctly, it compares the `element[minimum]` with the next elements `element[i]` and swaps positions if `element[i] < element[minimum]`. Then it repeats this with `element[i + 1]` until the list is sorted.

Now when I try it with the following code, I get an incorrect sort and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
public static void SelectionSort1(int[] list){
    for (int i = 0; i < (list.length - 1); i++){
        int min =  i; 
        for (int j = i + 1; j<list.length; j++){
            if(list[j] < list[min]){
                min = j;
            }
            int smallernumber = list[i];
            list[i] = list[min];
            list[min] = smallernumber;
        }
    }
}


public static void main (String [] args){

    int[] list = {5,4,2,1,3};

    System.out.println("Before Sort" + Arrays.toString(list));
    SelectionSort1(list);
    System.out.println("After Sort " + Arrays.toString(list));
}
```

****My output is: 


Before Sort[5, 4, 2, 1, 3]

After Sort [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]****

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Don't do the swap in the nested for-loop. You need to first find the min, THEN swap it.

Comment: Oh wow stupid me, you're right!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is almost correct, it compares the `element[minimum]` with the next elements `element[j]` and `if element[j] < element[minimum]` then the minimum index is equal to j. Then it repeats until j reaches the end of the array. After it swaps the index at `element[i]` with `element[minimum]`.

What this is doing is swapping `element[i]` with the smallest number to the right of index i. Then moving index i to the next spot. Repeating this gives you a sorted array.

TLDR:
Move the swapping outside of the second for loop. It should be:

```
public static void SelectionSort1(int[] list){
    for (int i = 0; i < (list.length - 1); i++){
        int min =  i; 
        for (int j = i + 1; j<list.length; j++){
            if(list[j] < list[min]){
                min = j;
            }
        }
            int smallernumber = list[i];
            list[i] = list[min];
            list[min] = smallernumber;
        
    }
}
```